# Can kafka server force consumer properties?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am relatively new to Kafka world. I could setup a kafka consumer in Java and can see that consumer API allows me to set consumer properties.

```
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG,2000);
new KafkaConsumer<>(properties)
```

This is working fine for me. I also see a file on kafka server with name consumer.properties. I thought that if I configure max.poll.interval.ms to some value in this file then I need not configure it in consumer code. But this is not working. Is it the case that I cannot decide consumer properties from server side? I think it will be better if kafka server decides the heartbeat time or timeout time instead of consumer. Is there any other setting that I must do on kafka server to force consumer properties? I have gone through Kafka documentation but could not find anything related to this. It looks like consumer.properties file has to be written and then that has to be passed to consumer API. Please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: One alternative would be to wrap kafka consumer to a java lib with the consumer properties, and all your applications can import and use this lib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no *global configuration* for Kafka consumers. The `consumer.properties` file is usually used for Kafka console consumers. For example,

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic myTopic --from-beginning --consumer.config consumer.properties
```

Alternatively, if you want to make use of the file in the context of a Java Consumer, you can read the `consumer.properties` as usual and set the corresponding properties. For example,

```
Properties consumerProps = new Properties();

try {

    consumerProps.load(App.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("config.properties"));

    // Add any other properties you may wish..

    KafkaConsumer consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerProps)

} 
catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```